# by_distance method not working (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, geolocation, geokit

So, I'm using geokit-rails and I would like to sort by distance, specifically showing the nearest meals first and descending from there. e.g. 5km, 10km, 15km.

However, for some reason the distance_by method isn't working at all, and the distances are all over the place.

This is how we're using it:

```
    all_venues = Venue.where(
      'listed = ? AND packages_count > ?', true, 0
    ).by_distance(origin: search_location).search(params[:search]) || Venue.where(listed: true).all
```

Are there any work around methods to use? Or how can I sort from nearest to furthest with geokit-rails?

Thanks!

Comment: Try switching the order of the method chaining? Venue.by_distance...

Comment: also, https://github.com/geokit/geokit-rails states (under "important caveat") that building queries with where clauses is cumbersome at best.